# Oracle pipelined table and Materialzed View

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a TYPE defined in Oracle, which I also have a function that returns a collection of the TYPE. So something like:

TYPE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE mildap as object
(then my type definition here)
```

THE COLLECTION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE mildaps AS TABLE of mildap;
```

THE FUNCTION:

```
FUNCTION F_TESTQUERY RETURN mildaps
(function work is here to populate mildaps)
```

When I execute a SQL query to return the mildap I get the results just as expected. That looks like this:

```
select * from table(F_TESTQUERY)
```

Due to the work that the function is doing it runs pretty slow, so what I was wanting to do is materialize it...like so:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW WEVLDAP_MV
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
START WITH TO_DATE('29-04-2015', 'DD-MM-YYYY') NEXT TRUNC(SYSDATE +1) 
AS
select *
from table(F_TESTQUERY);
```

But what I get is a ORA-06502 numeric or value error.

Is it possible to materialize in this way?...any ideas?

Comment: I've tried to create your types and function in my test schema, then i created a materialized view. And materialized view is working without any errors. (Oracle 11.2). For type mildap I've got `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE mildap AS OBJECT (ID NUMBER);` just for the experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW WEVLDAP_MV
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
START WITH TO_DATE('29-04-2015', 'DD-MM-YYYY') NEXT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')+1
AS
select *
from table(F_TESTQUERY);
```

Regards.